# Postgres Insert An Array without a Loop

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am passing an array of values from Npgsql to a function that inserts multiple rows at a time, and returns the auto-assigned serial ids.  The following is the code that I have working on the server side:

```
CREATE TABLE "MyTable" (
    "ID" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "Value" DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL
);

CREATE TYPE "MyTableType" AS (
    "Value" DOUBLE PRECISION
);

CREATE FUNCTION "InsertIntoMyTable"(entries "MyTableType"[])
    RETURNS SETOF INT AS $$

    DECLARE
        insertCmd TEXT := 'INSERT INTO "MyTable" ("Value") '
            'VALUES ($1) RETURNING "ID"';
        entry "MyTableType";
    BEGIN
        FOREACH entry IN ARRAY entries LOOP
            RETURN QUERY EXECUTE insertCmd USING entry."Value";
        END LOOP;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

My question is, is there some way to insert each array value as a row without looping over the array?  For example, is there some Postgres syntax to make the following implementation possible:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "InsertIntoMyTable"(entries "MyTableType"[])
    RETURNS SETOF INT AS $$

    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO "MyTable" ("Value")
            SELECT "Value" FROM entries
            RETURNING "ID";
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

The goal is to perform these inserts as fast as possible, as it is the most frequent task done by my production system.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run than they are worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `unnest()` function to convert the array into a set:

```
INSERT INTO "MyTable" ("Value")
SELECT i
from unnest(entries) i;
```